# Why use listento instead of on when listening to events?

Tags: backbone.js

Why use listento instead of on when listening to Backbone events? It seems to be they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

See below:
listenTo and stopListening came from the community, basically. They help to make it easier to bind and unbind events.

You can read here

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/10/01/backbone-eventbinder-better-event-management-for-your-backbone-apps/

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/

Listento:

Tell an object to listen to a particular event on an other object. The advantage of using this form, instead of other.on(event, callback, object), is that listenTo allows the object to keep track of the events, and they can be removed all at once later on. The callback will always be called with object as context.

On:

onobject.on(event, callback, [context])Alias: bind 
Bind a callback function to an object. The callback will be invoked whenever the event is fired. If you have a large number of different events on a page, the convention is to use colons to namespace them: "poll:start", or "change:selection". The event string may also be a space-delimited list of several events...